# Run doesn't work, class not used in launchers?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm relatively new to (Java) programming. Was following a tutorial on youtube using **Libgdx** and making and combining things for my own testgame. Everything worked fine, until I moved files from my Game class to a PlayScreen and MainMenu class, following the tutorial. **Run as** doesn't do anything anymore. In the Android and Desktoplauncher file it says: import com.me.Game.*; is not being used. Furthermore it doesn't really give any errormessages, it just doesnt do anything anymore. Tried deleting the project and reimporting it again. This is some part of the logfile from .metadata though i don't really understand it much. I feel like it's a pretty obvious error but I'm just not seeing it, any pointing in a possible right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\android\bin\res.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting resources.
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Could not delete '/DodgeRun-android/bin/res'.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.delete(FileSystemResourceManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1983)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:769)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.clean(PostCompilerBuilder.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder$2.run(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\android\bin\res.
!SUBENTRY 4 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting resources.
!SUBENTRY 5 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting files.
!SUBENTRY 6 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Could not delete: C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\android\bin\res.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting resources.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Could not delete '/DodgeRun-android/bin/res'.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.delete(FileSystemResourceManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1983)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:769)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.clean(PostCompilerBuilder.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder$2.run(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\android\bin\res.
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting resources.
!SUBENTRY 4 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting files.
!SUBENTRY 5 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2015-03-22 10:47:33.854
!MESSAGE Could not delete: C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\android\bin\res.
!SESSION 2015-03-22 11:02:58.893 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_75
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_NL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-03-22 11:03:08.368
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-03-22 11:03:08.370
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Gebruiker'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.323
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.all

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.324
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.sourcefolders

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.325
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.dependencies

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.326
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.DisableGradleNatureAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.327
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.EnableDisableDependencyManagementActionDelegate

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.328
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.EnableDisableDSLSupportDelegate

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 11:22:11.332
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.Console
!SESSION 2015-03-22 12:40:35.929 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_75
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_NL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-03-22 12:40:45.610
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.462
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.all

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.463
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.sourcefolders

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.464
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.actions.refresh.dependencies

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.465
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.DisableGradleNatureAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.466
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.EnableDisableDependencyManagementActionDelegate

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.467
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.EnableDisableDSLSupportDelegate

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-03-22 12:41:00.468
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.actions.Console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.core 4 125 2015-03-22 12:42:17.003
!MESSAGE Exception occurred executing command line.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\core\bin\com\me\DodgeRun\DodgeRun.class" (in directory "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\DodgeRun\core"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.core.externaltools.internal.launchConfigurations.ProgramLaunchDelegate.launch(ProgramLaunchDelegate.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Thanks for the people voting down this topic. The error or actually lack of errors is really unclear for me so if people could give any pointers on how I could make this topic more "clear" that would also be appreciated. Am already googling for 2 days atm. Would appreciate some tips instead of the nice voting down :)

Answer (score 1):

> Problems encountered while deleting files.

is just eclipse internal error. Restarting eclipse, deleting files manually or using something similar to [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) should help with that issue.

For "moving code block" problem, post your files pre-move and post-move.

Lastly, Eclipse is no longer official IDE for Android. Consider moving to Android Studio (also it would help to know how will Android Studio deal with your error).